# React Native Touchable in one row

Tags: react-native

I'm facing a problem and I'm not able to find a solution for this. I want two touchable buttons in one row for some actions. The problem is, when I click one one of them the onPress event of the other button get's hit too. What is wrong here? This is my code:

My Component:

```
      <View style={styles.actionContainer}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleState} style={styles.action}>
          {favorite ? (
            <AntDesign name="heart" size={30} color={colors.secondary} />
          ) : (
            <AntDesign name="hearto" size={30} color={colors.tab} />
          )}
          <TextCmpt style={styles.iconTagline}>In deinen Korb</TextCmpt>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.action}>
          {favorite ? (
            <AntDesign name="checkcircle" size={30} color={colors.tab} />
          ) : (
            <AntDesign
              name="checkcircleo"
              size={30}
              color={colors.secondary}
            />
          )}
          <TextCmpt style={styles.iconTagline}>Direkt sichern</TextCmpt>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
```

My styleSheet:

```
 actionContainer: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "center",
    margin: 20,
  },
  action: {
    // position: "absolute",
    alignItems: "center",
    borderRadius: 10,
    backgroundColor: colors.primary,
    justifyContent: "center",
    height: 80,
    width: "100%",
  },
```

Comment: You seem to have only `onPress` event on your button

Comment: Oh yes, you are right. But this is not the issue. I just removed one onPress for testing.

Comment: Can you create an expo [here](https://snack.expo.io/) to check?

Comment: hey, your code is working fine on my side. you can also try to remove **position:"absolute"**

Comment: Thank you guys! I found the problem. I've used the same variable "favourite" for rendering dynamically so the buttons changed both and it looked like both touchable events where pressed.